# What's the syntax of drush generate --answers argument?

Tags: drush

So I am trying to automate theme creation using drush.
There is no documentation on how to fill the --answers argument there 
https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/core/generate/

I have tried:

```
drush generate theme --answers='{"Theme name":"test", "Theme machine name":"test", "Base theme":"Classy"}'
```

to no avail:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found it:

```
drush generate theme --directory themes/custom --answers '{"name": "test", "machine_name": "test", "base_theme": "Classy"}'
```

in the absence of documentation, you'll find the needed json keys in the sources of drush code generator:

```
/sources/vendor/chi-teck/drupal-code-generator/src/Command/Drupal_8/Theme.php
```

in the "interact" method

Answer (score 2):

You just need a space after --answers instead of =

```
drush generate theme --answers '{"Theme name": "test", "Theme machine name": "test", "Base theme": "Classy"}'
```

Different command, but same structure as shown here: https://cog-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#command-line-options

Comment: you are right about the space instead of the = but the keys are not good with that command => see my answer

Comment: @thony Glad you got it working! Sorry I was focused on the syntax and didn't realize you were looking for the available arguments to. :)

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of `drush` does not use JSON format for anwers anymore. Instead it accepts a sequence of answers like follows.

```
drush generate theme --answer=Test --answer=test --answer=classy --answer= --answer=
```

Note that for empty anwers the default value will be used.